# how to implement event handling in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

In my shell script, im deleting a file at the end of script. And i need it to be deleted even if the script was stopped by (ctrl c or ctrl z)..Is there any way to read that and delete the file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @pgl said, `trap` is what you want. The syntax is:

`trap <actionhere> <event> [event...]`

The action is one and only one argument, but it can run several commands. The event is either `exit` (when you call `exit` manually) or a signal by its "short" name, ie without the `SIG` prefix (for instance, `INT` for `SIGINT`.

Example:

`trap "rm -f myfile" INT exit`

You can change the trap all along the script. And of course, you can use variable interpolation in your action.

Comment: I want to know more about shell's event programming syntax, example codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch ctrl+c's with the `trap` builtin. Try this to get started:

```
help trap
```